# ColorPicker installation (jQuery plugin)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

[Implementation instruction](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#implement)

**using angular-cli**

I downloaded the whole package and uploaded into `public/javascripts`.
Inside `angular-cli.json` I added these lines:

```
  "styles": [
    (...)
    "../public/javascripts/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css",
  ],
  "scripts": [
    (...)
    "../public/javascripts/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js"
  ],
```

How could I use it now inside component view?